# Vertically centering child div in parent container with JavaScript on page load is not setting position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript to vertically center a child div within a fluid container. I essentially accomplish this by calculating the height of the parent container and the height of the child div. I then absolutely positon the child div in the center of the parent div based on the height. The issue I am experiencing is that when the page loads, it does not set the position of the child div. I created a function out of this and call it when the window is resized so that when the viewport changes it recalculates dynamically. How would I go about initially setting this position on page load?

```
<div class="lead">
    <div class="message"></div>
</div>

var homepageLead = function () {
var lead = $('.lead'),
    message = $('.message'),
    lead_height = lead.height(),
    message_height = message.height(),
    lead_center = .5 * lead_height,
    message_center = .5 * message_height,
    center = (lead_center - message_center);    
message.css('bottom',center);
}
homepageLead();

$(window).resize(function () {
    homepageLead();
});
```

Comment: is this js inside a doc ready? i.e: $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: It's inside of a: (function ($) {})(jQuery);

Comment: can you edit your question's code to include this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nRRn6/

### used css:

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
.lead {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:red;
   position:relative;
}
.message {
   width:120px;
   height:200px;
   background:yellow;
   position:absolute;  /* <---required*/
   left:0;             /* <---required*/
   bottom:0;           /* <---required*/
}
```

### used html:

```
<div class="lead">
    <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

### used jQuery:

```
var homepageLead = function () {
    var lead = $('.lead'),
        message = $('.message'),
        lead_height = lead.height(),
        message_height = message.height(),
        lead_center = .5 * lead_height,
        message_center = .5 * message_height,
        center = (lead_center - message_center);
    return message.css('bottom', center);
};

$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        homepageLead();
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what's going on here, you are setting a default left and bottom position of 0 so that the browser initially has a value before the js loads in a sets it?

Comment: When the page loads I'm experiencing a slight hickup as the .message div starts at the bottom of the .lead container (I'm guessing the browser is trying to calculate the height of the div) and then it jumps up to the correct vertical center position. What's the best way to prevent this from happening?