# vertically align child div with jquery jumps on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning from the technique here:

[Vertically centering child div in parent container with JavaScript on page load is not setting position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918181/vertically-centering-child-div-in-parent-container-with-javascript-on-page-load)

This allows me to vertically center a div, when I don't know the height of the container.

All works well, however in Safari 7.0.1 and Chrome 32.0.1700.77 the vertically aligned div moves up by around 30px on browser resize. In Firefox, it just displays where Safari and Chrome moves the div to on browser resize (no jump).

On load, before browser resize:

```
<div id="s1" class="wrp_item" style="bottom: 257.1px;">
```

After browser resize:

```
<div id="s1" class="wrp_item" style="bottom: 286.2px;">
```

You can see an example of the code/markup I'm using here, although I can't replicate the issue on the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RKhmY/

Online demo reproducing the bug in Safari/Chrome. Notice how in firefox the bug does not display:
http://so.s2371.gridserver.com/test.html

Any ideas where the extra pixels are coming from on browser resize, thus causing the jump?

Answer (score 0):

You are already binding the window resize handler within a dom ready handler so there is no need to use this syntax

```
$(function () { //This line should be removed
    $(window).resize(function () {
        homepageLead();
    }).resize();
}); //This line should be removed
```

Just remove `$(function () {` and `});`

http://jsfiddle.net/RKhmY/2/

Comment: This didn't prevent the jump on browser resize. It's almost like on page load isn't being positioned correctly. On browser resize it's displaying the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe does it help if you do it another way:

- Align the content (#s1) 50% from top with css.
- Get height of the content (#s1).
- Give the content (#s1) the negative margin of the height of the content / 2.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKhmY/4/)

CSS:

```
div.relative { position: relative; }
section#hero div.item, section#hero { min-height: 750px; position: relative;}
section#hero .wrp_item { width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 50%;}
section#hero .wrp_item .wrp_item_inner { padding: 0px 20px; }
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var homepageLead = function () {
                var message = $('#s1'),
                    message_height = message.height();
                return message.css('margin-top', -message_height / 2);
            };

            $(function () {
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    homepageLead();
                }).resize();
            });

    // end     
    });
```

Comment: Nice approach and thanks for cleaning up the JS. Unfortunately, the jump is still there between on load and browser resize. This jump only happens with Safari & Chrome.

Comment: I tried using margin-top, paddingTop, top, bottom. doesn't matter where I positioned the div, i still get this jump on browser resize.

Comment: Try message.outerHeight(); instead of message.height(); in the jQuery. If this solves the problem, its because .height() doesn't calculate the padding of the div.

Comment: I'ved tried height, outerHeight & innerHeight. All producing the same results.

Comment: Can you put a test online so i can see the issue?

Comment: If there's an example online of the issue i could check the code and maybe solve the problem. Otherwise i can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think this could be a bug with my CSS. I have tried other plugins with the same bug.

For reference, if anybody has the same problem, the below link worked for me without any jump:

https://github.com/BrandonJacoby/Midway.js